Exception thrown ntdll.dll 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
My current project consists of migrating an old version of boost build system to the current version and I am going from 32-bit to 64-bit model. Because of this, I had to make changes in building platforms in Visual Studio 2022 and some applications on my project seems to output this exception after I close the application.
I have tried to change from WIN32 platform to 64 when building and this fixes some linking errors that I previously had when building with the new boost version. However, this exception occurs and I think this could be because my application hasn't fully adapted to 64 and I don't really know why or how to debug this.

Is there a link to the project. Because without any code, all bets are off. We can just tell you have UB, likely due to ODR violation or potentially a corrupt pointer value. That's it. It's unclear how "my application hasn't fully adapted to 64"  could be. The most sensible explanation I can think of is that you are mixing ported and unported dynamic libraries. That's definitely ABI incompatible (so ODR violations).
